# NoReverseMatch at /create/

Tags: python, django

I want to create a system. For this system I need to a patient create form. When I click the button, I can save the patient but there is a error page after I pushed it.

> Reverse for 'create' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'title-1'}' not
>   found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create/$']

Where is my mistakes? Thanks a lot.

**views.py**

```
def patient_create(request):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "http404.html")

    form = PatientForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        post.save()
        messages.Info(request, "Success!!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(newPatients.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "patient_form.html", context)
```

**models.py**

```
class newPatients(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
dept = models.TextField()
address = models.TextField()
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
notes = RichTextField(verbose_name="notes")
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True, editable=False)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_create_url(self):
    return reverse('post:create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

def get_unique_slug(self):
    slug = slugify(self.title.replace('ı', 'i'))
    unique_slug = slug
    counter = 1
    while newPatients.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
        counter += 1
    return unique_slug

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post:create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = self.get_unique_slug()
    return super(newPatients, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_date']
```

**traceback**

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/

Django Version: 2.2.9
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users',
 'patients',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\pharsys\patients\views.py" in patient_create
  31.         return HttpResponseRedirect(newPatients.get_absolute_url())

Exception Type: TypeError at /create/
Exception Value: get_absolute_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Please actually provide the relevant context. You have shared a lot of code, not the part where it is going wrong though. From the traceback you can see it goes wrong when `newPatients.get_absolute_url()` is called. To be able to know what is going wrong we have to know where this `newPatients` is created. Is it a class, import reference, object etc?

Comment: newPatients in my models.py and it is in the question, sir

Comment: No it is not. Your question has to do with the fact that the function is improperly called. Therefore I have to know if the newPatients in views.py is an instance of your class, or a reference to the class itself. Simply said: we need to know its initialisation, which is **not** in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the method on the `patient` that you constructed, not on the `newPatients` class:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def patient_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatientForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            patient = form.save()
            messages.Info(request, "Success!!")
            return redirect(patient)
    else:
        form = PatientForm()
    # …
```

Note that normally a model name is not coupled to a certain action, so `newPatients` is a bit *odd*. Likely `Patient` is a better name.

You furthermore better use [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) here, since this will automatically call `get_absolute_url` for a model instance.

Finally you can use the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) to use a uniform way of enforcing that the user has logged in.

Comment: Thank you very much! But now, this happens: TypeError at /create/
get_absolute_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Do you know why?

Comment: @JackNiv: did you pass the `patient` object (from `patient = form.save()`), or the `newPatient` class?

Comment: oh, I missed one of them. Thank you very much